# Scala compile time error: No implicits found for parameter evidence$2: BodyWritable[Map[String, Object]]

Tags: java, scala, rest, functional-programming, playframework-2.6

I am working on scala play framework application. I am trying to call a web service API which takes request payload data as follows

```
{
    "toID": [
        "email1@email.com",
        "email2@email.com"
    ],
    "fromID": "info@test.com",
    "userID": "ervd12fdsfksdjnfn9832rbjfdsnf",
    "mailContent": "Dear Sir, ..."
}
```

And for this I am using following code

```
ws.url(Utils.messengerServiceUrl + "service/email")
          .post(
            Map("userID" -> userID, "mailContent" -> userData.message, "fromID" -> "info@test.com", "toID" -> userData.emails)).map { response =>
          println(response.body, response.status)
        }
```

So for this code, compiler is complaining about **"toID" -> userData.emails** saying **No implicits found for parameter evidence$2: BodyWritable[Map[String, Object]]**

So my question is how to send such data using WSClient?

Comment: What type of `userData.emails`?

Comment: userData.emails's type is Seq[String]

Comment: Why you send it as a map? You could create case class that describe the payload like `case class Message(toID: Seq[String], fromID: String, userID: String, mailContent: String)`

Comment: I am new to scala play framework and this is the only way I know to send payload data. I created case class and tried replacing Map with Message(userID, userData.message, "info@test.com", userData.emails) but then it is displaying similar error like BodyWritable[Message]. So can you please give me one example of sending case class object as payload data.

Comment: You need to specify json encoder for that case class `Writes[Message]` and pass it implicitly, e.g. `implicit val messageWrites = Json.writes[Message]`

Comment: `Object` or `Any` are generally symptoms of something bad, and typeclasses won't work properly in such case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with case class like that

```
import play.api.libs.json._


case class Message(toID: Seq[String], fromID: String, userID: String, mailContent: String)

object Message {
  implicit val writes: Writes[Message] = Json.writes[Message]
}
```

Pay attention to the definition of the `object Message` with `implicit writes`