# No implicits found for parameter evidence$2: BodyWritable[Map[String, Object]]

Tags: json, scala, playframework, ws

Working on play ws and have to prepare request param as **{"initVideoUploadParams": {"videoMetadataParams":{"metadata":{"name":"","description":""}}}}** . Tried the solution given in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102698/scala-compile-time-error-no-implicits-found-for-parameter-evidence2-bodywrita) but didn't worked as my case is not similar to that question.
Below is the code snippet

```
ws.url(savaUrl+configObj.get[String]("kaltura.init"))
                        .post(Map("initVideoUploadParams" -> InitVideoUploadParams(fileName,fileName)))
```

And the case class

```
case class InitVideoUploadParams(name:String,desc:String)

object InitVideoUploadParams {

  implicit object InitVideoUploadParamsWrites {
    def writes(name:String,desc:String): JsObject = Json.obj(
      "videoMetadataParams" -> VideoMetadataParams(Utils.createVideoParamsMap(name,desc)).metadata
    )   } }

case class VideoMetadataParams(metadata: Map[String, String])

object VideoMetadataParams {   implicit object VideoMetadataParamsWrites {
    def writes(metadata:Map[String,String]): JsObject = Json.obj(
      "metadata" -> metadata
    )   } }
```

Gone through the play [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaWS) but not able to implement.
Help me to understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Your case class looks wrong. Are you sure it should be a map? In the example you linked it looks like this : case class Message(toID: Seq[String], fromID: String, userID: String, mailContent: String)

object Message {
  implicit val writes: Writes[Message] = Json.writes[Message]
}

Comment: The final request JSON I want is {"initVideoUploadParams": {"videoMetadataParams":{"metadata":{"name":"","description":""}}}}
So I added Map[String,String] for the metatdata. If not Map then what else I should use? @GamingFelix

Comment: In the example, the map is the json. So the JSON become a map in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to `POST` a value of type `Map[String, InitVideoUploadParams]` with Play-WS. In order for Play to know how to serialize that type to JSON, there needs to be an object of type `Writes[InitVideoUploadParams]` in the implicit scope. Apparently you were trying to do that with those `implicit object`s, but you need to extend `Writes` for that to work:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json.Writes
object InitVideoUploadParams {
  implicit object InitVideoUploadParamsWrites extends Writes[InitVideoUploadParams] {
    def writes(o: InitVideoUploadParams): JsValue = {
      ??? // implementation goes here
    }
  }
}
```

But it's a bit simpler to instead use the methods on the `Writes` companion object:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json.Writes
object InitVideoUploadParams {
  implicit val writes: Writes[InitVideoUploadParams] = Writes { o =>
    ??? //implementation goes here
  }
}
```